# Can we talk about employer copyright assignment?

Tags: discussion, legal

Some employers claim to own all code written by their employees at any time, even when at home and using personal equipment.  Some employers have vague contracts which do not spell this out one way or the other.  And finally, there are some employers who explicitly assign these copyrights to the employee.  Without getting too much into the morality or legality of these varying stances, **how should affected employees best contribute to Stack Overflow?**

I can see several possible answers:

1. **Do not contribute (nontrivial) code in questions or in answers at all.**  Avoiding code in questions is clearly unworkable unless we want to eliminate the [MCVE rule](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Avoiding code in answers may be doable, and could even improve the quality of one's answers, but it is a tax on one's time, and will basically remove one from contention in [FGITW questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) (which is a lot of them in my experience).  Finally, this is not extensible to Code Review.SE, whose questions and answers pretty much *always* involve code.
2. **Add an exception to both the [upcoming MIT license](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange) (assuming it gets off the ground) and the existing CC-BY-SA license to allow for this problem.**  I... really don't like this solution, but it's there.  Obviously, this makes reuse of Stack Overflow code much harder, but it might be better to explicitly acknowledge this problem rather than ignore it as we've been doing.  Sadly, this is probably the most workable solution, in terms of not requiring large numbers of contributors to stop contributing.
3. **Get a copyright waiver from one's employer for every single question or answer with nontrivial code.**  Unworkable for those who participate at high volume, and even worse for the FGITW problem.  Some employers will not grant these, or will not grant them quickly enough to matter.
4. Something else?
5. **Just ignore the problem**.  This is potentially problematic for anyone trying to reuse SO code.  It utterly guts the MIT dual licensing scheme because that license simply will not be reliable.  You cannot MIT license code which you do not own.  Without a valid license, downstream reusers become liable for copyright infringement (though the lack of intent [may reduce damages](http://www3.ce9.uscourts.gov/jury-instructions/node/286), it [does not eliminate](http://www3.ce9.uscourts.gov/jury-instructions/node/285) the tort).  This option can be most expeditiously supported by downvoting or ignoring this question.

Comment: This may be too broad to be answerable... I would assume the answer would depend on an individual's contract and how enforceable it really is.

Comment: @apaul34208: If we're contemplating changing the licensing terms, that needs to take place in a public forum.

Comment: Is option 4 to find a better job that doesn't have such an idiotic contract? But to be serious, those statements are to scare employees. I doubt any court would recognize them for any code that wasn't directly related to their job or something they've done there. That would be like saying "we're giving you a uniform allowance, so we now own all clothes you purchase while you work for us." Unless someone creates a legal precedent for it (which is unlikely to ever happen), I don't see much point in discussing it.

Comment: @animuson: You may feel that way, but if I am trying to figure something out, I ask SO for help, and I later get dragged into a lengthy copyright lawsuit, I will not be happy, even if the lawsuit turns out to be groundless.  We should at least have a formal policy on this.

Comment: The only policy we can have is don't post code you know belongs to your employer. Having other policies won't prevent you from getting into a copyright battle if you have a crappy employer that wants to make your life miserable. If a user is honestly *so afraid* to post any code on Stack Overflow because their employer might sue them over it, then they seriously should look for a different job. That's certainly not a place I would want to work.

Comment: @animuson: You are not considering this from the reuser's perspective.  The average SO contributor takes precisely the same view as you do: the agreement is either unenforceable or irrelevant.  But as a reuser, *I can't afford that luxury*.  If there is any question as to the copyright status of some code, I cannot safely use it.

Comment: Is this question about using code you've found posted on the site or about posting code to the site?

Comment: @apaul34208: The latter, but we must respect the needs of the former.

Comment: [The former is already covered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange)

Comment: @apaul34208: You can't license code you don't own.

Comment: @animuson Does SE have a legal department, or in house lawyer, that could field these sort of questions? It may be worthwhile to ask the company to produce a canonical "everything you need to know about licensing" maybe even a help center page.

Comment: @apaul34208 We don't. We consult with lawyers when consulting is warranted for specific cases. I believe lawyers were involved during discussions about switching to the MIT license, but I wasn't there so I can't tell you about any concerns they might have brought up.

Comment: @animuson Just thinking that a faq written by someone with some qualification/authority may be helpful.

Comment: Very relevant: http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6004/am-i-liable-for-the-unlicenced-use-of-something-licensed-to-me-by-someone-withou

Comment: Such a clause in an employment contract is used by a company to cover themselves against a [case like this one](https://majadhondt.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/googles-9-lines/).  Just big boys assisted by expensive pit-bulls fighting over your work, this will not affect you personally.  Other than you being able to charge a very considerable expert testimony fee :)

Answer (score 15):

[Stack Exchange TOS, 3. Subscriber Content](https://stackexchange.com/legal)

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license. [...]

This is, in my non-lawyer opinion, the only sane way of handling things, i.e.: **if you don't own sufficient rights on the code to post it, *don't post it***.

Doesn't matter if it's a restrictive contract you're under, or if you found something on the web somewhere you'd like to copy-paste.

Your option 5 is plain damaging to both sides. Option 2 completely breaks the Stack Exchange model. Some form of options 3 could be workable for some people and option 1 obviously is - yes, it might prevent someone from participating, but that's a problem between that person and their employer, not something Stack Exchange can do anything about.

So I'd fill option 4 with: follow the terms of service. If, because of some contract you're bound to, this restricts your use of this network of sites, that's a matter between you and the other contracting party, not something Stack Exchange can fix.

Please don't change SE to allow some posts to become "proprietary", or "you can read but can't use", or whatever exceptions your were thinking about in your second case.